# (crystal reports) How to decrease RPT file size

Tags: image, crystal-reports

I'm trying to decrease size of my rpt file. The problem is in image. When I remove image, file is about 50KB size large. When I add image, it increases to 600KB.

I reduced resulution of my image. It has only 12KB. I tried to use JPG, PNG, TIFF. With bigger image, size of rpt file is growing (for 200KB image it is about 2MB rpt)

Do you have any solution to this problem?

Regards,

-- Marcin Krupowicz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hai,

Try Inserting the image as an OLE object instead of as a picture object

Comment: I put the image into Microsoft Word document and add it to rpt as OLE object. It didn't help :-/

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/ca4e29b5-4589-402f-bd51-2f5cc87311f8

Comment: Thanks a lot! Decreasing colors depth helped. Crystal converts images to bmp, so the best idea is to add image as bmp. I did it with image of color depth 256 and saved as BMP.

Comment: This answer didn't help me, but the comment above did.